# list all only files in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to list all the files included in folder using following php scripts:

```
$dir = 'd:/temp_file/voice/';
if (is_dir($dir)) {
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                echo "filename: ".$file."<br />";
        }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
```

The problem is that it also shows the folder with . name which output is shown below. How can I avoid those folder.

```
filename: .
filename: ..
filename: _19031265739am014771957.wav
filename: _19031265758am014771957.wav
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using if statement... ?

`if($file != '.' && $file != '..')`

if you want to filter out all directories (not just . and ..):

`if(is_file($dir . $file))`